# Scanning Java Code for Strings

Tags: java, cucumber

So I'd like to know if there is any easy way to scan through certain files in your code based on extension. Specifically, I'm using Java and would like to scan through .feature files because I need to create something with that information.

I know that PMD is a thing, but with many hours invested in it I can not figure out how to use it and was wondering if there is an easier way without the overhead of reporting, rule detection and what not that PMD offers.

Thanks

Comment: What, you need `grep` implemented in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know where the files are, you can do something like ...

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Then you can `for` through the elements and get the extension by

```
String type = "";
for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; ++i){
    int extensionLocation = listOfFiles[i].lastIndexOf('.');
    type = listOfFiles[i].getName().substring(extensionLocation);
    //Once you have the type you can do something here.

}
```